# Jquery.clean method documented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, documentation, jquery-1.8

I have to update some code using jquery and I have the following statements :

```
 $.each($.clean({0:data}, this.ownerDocument), fct);
```

Where data is html content from server.

I didn't find any documentation about this method.

I just know that [Jquery 1.9 remove it](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#other-undocumented-properties-and-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Those methods are not meant to be used outside of jQuery, that's why you are having so much trouble finding documentation on them.